# How to implement simple react js animation with react-pose without node js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-pose

I am newbie in react js. Recently I went through the react js [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/) and react-pos [documentation](https://popmotion.io/pose/learn/install/). I have implemented the following snippet. But when I run it, it has no effect in the browser. Where am I wrong?

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.box{
    background:red;
 }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"> 
</script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.15.0/babel.min.js"> 
</script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-pose/dist/react-pose.js"></script>

<div style="width:200px; height:200px; background:#eaeaea;" id="root"></div>

<script>
    const Box = posed.div({
      hidden: { opacity: 0 },
      visible: { opacity: 1 }
    });

    class Example extends React.Component {
      state = { isVisible: true };

      componentDidMount() {
        setInterval(() => {
          this.setState({ isVisible: !this.state.isVisible });
        }, 1000);
      }

      render() {
        const { isVisible } = this.state;
        return <Box className="box" pose={isVisible ? 'visible' : 'hidden'} 
  />;
      }
    }

    ReactDOM.render(<Example/>, document.getElementById('root'));
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this:

```
<Box className="box" style={{visible: this.state.isVisible, hidden: !this.state.isVisible}} />;
```

Either way, you need to use **this.state.isVisible**, not just isVisible..

Comment: OP is destructuring `isVisible` on the previous line, so just `isVisible` will work. `const { isVisible } = this.state;`

Comment: @Tholle - ah yes didn't notice that!

Answer (score 0):

If you use `babel-standalone` for experimentation, you need to make sure you set the `type` attribute of your script to `text/babel`.

```css
.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-pose@3.1.0/dist/react-pose.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.15.0/babel.min.js"> 
</script>

<div id="root"></div>

<script type="text/babel">
const Box = posed.div({
  hidden: { opacity: 0 },
  visible: { opacity: 1 }
});
 
class Example extends React.Component {
  state = { isVisible: true };

  componentDidMount() {
    setInterval(() => {
      this.setState({ isVisible: !this.state.isVisible });
    }, 1000);
  }

  render() {
    const { isVisible } = this.state;
    return <Box className="box" pose={isVisible ? "visible" : "hidden"} />;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById("root"));
</script>
```